# Metric for inter-model agreement?

Tags: classification, kullback-leibler, metric

I have a classification task, with 3 classes.

A model $M$ is a classifier that outputs the probability of the input being each of these classes. For example, for input $x$, I have $M(x)=[0.1, 0.2, 0.7]$ - which means that this model thinks the probability of $x$ being of class 3 is $0.7$. I'm not concerned with maximum etc, but the entire distribution.

I want to compare two models $M_1$ and $M_2$ like this, and how much they agree on a given dataset $\mathcal{X}$. I propose this metric:

$s(M_1, M_2) =  \dfrac{ \displaystyle \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}  KL\big(M_1(x) \; ||  \; M_2(x) \big)    }{ |\mathcal{X}| } $

Is this metric okay? I'm a bit uncomfortable with taking arithmetic mean of KL divergence. If not, is there a better/widely accepted metric?

Comment: Well, your metric isn't technically a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space), but that's not what you're asking. Whether this function is OK really depends on what you want it to quantify. What mathematical properties are you looking for?

Comment: @Galen I am not looking for any specific properties, just some quantification of "how much do these two models agree on this dataset".

Comment: You're dealing with math, so defining what you mean by "how much do these two models agree on this dataset" in terms of mathematics is my recommendation. Perhaps a [(statistical) divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_(statistics)#Definition) would suffice, not to be confused with the differential operator called [*divergence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence), for example?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why taking the arithmetic mean makes you uncomfortable? It may elucidate something about what you're looking for.

Comment: [Total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) is an option that does use [KLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) explicitly or averaging...

Comment: Or maybe some other [f-divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-divergence)?

Comment: @Galen Arithmetic Mean in, say, Mean Squared Error comes from rigorous treatment of the maximum likelihood estimate. Here, I'm just using it as a measure of central tendency - which, I'm not really sure why would it work. It might make more sense to use geometric mean, or AM of $e^{KL}$.

Comment: ^^^ I mean does **not** use... anyway, just spotted that typo.

Comment: True, OLS is well-studied and is in a certain sense optimal when certain assumptions (e.g. normality) are satisfied. Your proposed function will not have that. Do you know what sort of distributional assumptions you can make?

Comment: @Galen what I have are discrete distributions, and the component values range from 0 to 1 inclusive. the sum across the vector is 1 (by virtue of being a distribution).